# When is Cheng-Li-Yau heat kernel bound optimal?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, geometric-analysis

In his Inventiones paper "The geometric complexity of special Lagrangian
$T^{2}$-cones" M. Haskins has used Cheng-Li-Yau theorem to give a lower bound of area of minimal Lagrangian tori in $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$ (the theorem is in "Heat Equations on Minimal Submanifolds and Their Applications", Am J Mathematics). 
The setup is following:

Let $X=S^{2n-1} \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be the unit sphere. Choose $S^{n-1}\subset X$ defined by $Im(z_{i})=0$. Let $M^{n-1}$ be a compact manifold with boundary minimally immersed to $X$. Then the Laplace Beltrami operator $\Delta_{X}$ has a discrete set of eigenvalues $\mu_{i}$ (resp $\lambda_{i}$) over $L^{2}(S^{n-1})$ (resp $L^{2}(M)$). In this setting, CLY theorem asserts that: $\Sigma e^{-\lambda_{i} t} \leq \Theta\: \Sigma e^{-\mu_{i}t}$ for any $t >0$ (where $\Theta=Vol(M)/Vol(S^{n-1})$). My question is when (if ever) this bound is optimal for some $t=t_{0}$?

My training is mostly in algebraic geometry so less analytic answers are encouraged.

Comment: It is just localization formula

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit?